# WLST - how to check if a patch was installed?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, middleware, wlst, osb

I need to patch my Oracle but i want to check first if the patches that I want to install are already installed.
How can i do it with WLST? (I need to script it because i am going to use it on a lot of systems - middleware 11g)

thanks,
Gav.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `ORACLE_HOME` variable is set to the correct location, and invoke `ORACLE_HOME\opatch\opatch.bat lsinventory`.

You'll probably want to put the results of that in a file, and grep it looking for whatever it is you're looking for.

Comment: I can't find it there. I forgot to mention it before, but I am talking about OSB.

Answer (score 0):

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/scratch/app/product/fmw/obpinstall;export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/Opatch:$PATH; opatch lsinventory [-all] [patch desc]
```

Just mention the ORACLE_HOME attribute and run the following command in the terminal and it will output in descending order the list of all the available patches installed in that ORACLE_HOME